# Converting string to base36 inconsistencies between languages.

Tags: javascript, python, base36

I have noticed some inconsistencies between Python and JavaScript when converting a string to base36.

**Python Method:**

```
>>> print int('abcdefghijr', 36)
```

Result: 37713647386641447

**Javascript Method:**

```
<script>
    document.write(parseInt("abcdefghijr", 36));
</script>
```

Result: 37713647386641450

What causes the different results between the two languages? What would be the best approach to produce the same results irregardless of the language?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812096/javascript-large-integer-round-because-precision-why ; javascript doesn't have arbitrary precision big integers like Python does. (just typing `37713647386641447` into the javascript console will give you the same rounded value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That number takes 56 bits to represent. JavaScript's numbers are actually [double-precision binary floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision), or `double` for short. These are 64 bit in total, and can represent a far wider *range* of values than a 64 bit integers, but due to how they achieve that (they represent a number as `mantissa * 2^exponent`), they cannot represent *all* numbers in that range, just the ones that are a multiple of `2^exponent` where the multiple fits into the mantissa (which includes 2^0 = 1, so you get *all* integers the mantissa can handle directly). The mantissa is 53 bits, which is insufficient for this number. So it gets rounded to a number which *can* be represented.

What you can do is use an arbitrary precision number type defined by a third party library like `gwt-math` or `Big.js`. These numbers aren't hard to implement if you know your school arithmetic. Doing it efficiently is another matter, but also an area of extensive research. And not *your* problem if you use an existing library.